# How do I create and store notes, photos, and events for a calendar app?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-view

I'm a 16-year-old who's learnt a few other programming languages and has now begun learning Kotlin for Android app development. I want to create a calendar app in which clicking on a date in a calendarView can allow you to take notes for that date and put photos in the notes from your gallery.

I've tried my best to scour the internet for tutorials and solutions to my problem, but it has proved unfruitful. My goal is to create a new View in which the notes can be displayed. However, I don't know how to go about saving what the user writes and stores. I also don't know how I can create views through code and not the .xml file.

Comment: If you don't want to add your views to xml and directly want to add through code, I would suggest you to go through the tutorials for Jetpack Compose.

Comment: My goal is to store what the user has inputted for each date such that I can immediately instatiate a sort of 'template' note view that displays everything as they originally wrote and saved it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.